# Embedded Neo4j hangs on database cleaning

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I start my application on empty(new) Neo4j embedded database, try to clean it with a following method:

```
public static void cleanDb(Neo4jTemplate template) {
    template.query("MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r", null);
}
```

and after I initialize db with a set of sample data. At this stage, during this initialization I specially terminate my application process.

Right after that I'm repeating these steps and my application hangs on database cleaning stage..

What could be causing this and how to correctly solve this issue ? I don't see any exceptions in my console..

Comment: Is this the same like your other questions? I.e. it hangs on a large dataset? That's to be expected. Increase heap or do it in batches (see my answers to you other questions).

Comment: It also hangs even in batches

Comment: What does "hangs" mean?  How big is your DB?  How long are you waiting?  What does messages.log say?  What are your heap settings?

Comment: Nothing special in the log.. Application just stop execution on the line with DELETE query. I have 600MB database on my HDD(SSD), also I have added following VM arguments - -Xmx4g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Comment: I noticed that everything work properly if I use graphDatabaseService.shutdown(); method before terminating of my application.. Otherwise database is destroyed(Neo4j server also hangs on this corrupted db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue related to the following fix - https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/c9596af0d990d7dde9a9053799b7295985ae3c05

I have applied the changes from this commit and the issue is gone.

So, right now I'm waiting for Neo4j 2.2.4 release.

Do you know the planned release date for Neo4j 2.2.4 ?